# How do I set $TERM permanently in fish shell?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, dotfiles, fish

I use the [`fish` shell](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell). I'm trying to run `vim` inside `tmux` with the [solarized theme](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized), but the colors are broken unless I run:

```
set -lx TERM screen-256color-bce;
```

before running `tmux attach`.

It's annoying having to run this every day, so I want to set the TERM variable permanently. However, fish seems to ignore when I set this particular variable with `set -U`:

```
$ set -U foo bar; echo $foo
foo bar
$ set -U TERM screen-256color-bce; echo $TERM
TERM xterm
$ set -lx TERM screen-256color-bce; echo $TERM
TERM screen-256color-bce
```

I even tried putting `set -lx TERM screen-256color-bce` in `~/.config/fish/config.fish`, but a new fish (initiated outside `tmux`) always has `TERM` set to `xterm`.

Comment: Since this question was just upvoted, I should mention that I reported this as an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/806). It is known, and now documented, behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

```
set -gx TERM screen-256color-bce;
```

I had the exact same problem as you. replace the "l" with "g" as g means global.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it from the terminal using

```
set -Ux TERM screen-256color-bce
```

You don't need to put it in your config file this way.

- `-U` if for **U**niversal
- `-g` is for **G**lobal
- `-x` if for e**X**port

Comment: I'm not sure if this was the case at the beginning of last year, but it is not the case anymore. The problem is TERM is set as a global variable (`g`), meaning it ignores a universal (`U`) TERM variable.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Setting_the_correct_term

Comment: That page describes what I'm trying to do (set `TERM` to `screen-256color-bce`), but it doesn't explain why I can only set this variable locally in the fish shell.

Comment: set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

Comment: I have never used fish shell, so I may not be much help.  Try some debugging, but some echo statements just before the set and after, make sure they are run, and print the value of TERm right after it is set.... if the debug statements don't print, it is possible the script isn't being run.